# Meteor js, how to get side effect of updating whole client side document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have a Meteor method that I call from the client, which in turn updates all fields in a single document. In the last line of code below I try to immediately run the same update on the client to get the immediate side effects (it assumes the update will go through). The trouble is I get:

> update failed: Access denied. In a restricted collection you can only update documents, not replace them. Use a Mongo update operator, such as '$set'

when trying to do that. I don't want to update a single field, I want to update the whole document. Is there a way to do this properly?

```
entry = {
    title: title
    text: text
    tags: entry.tags
    mode: $('#mode').val()
    file_ids: entry.file_ids
}

eid = Session.get('entryId')
entry._id = eid if eid

context = Session.get('context')
Meteor.call('saveEntry', title, entry, context)
Entries.update({_id: entry._id}, entry)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'saveEntry' method?  You could just run update as part of that method which would avoid your issue.

Comment: yes, you are correct... see my comment added below the other answer, the secret here is stub methods as you alluded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like:

```
Entries.update({_id: entry._id}, { $set: entry })
```

A typical update request is on the form:

```
Collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>
)
```

From the Mongodb documentation, about updating with a regular key:value object:

> **Replace Document Entirely**
>
> If the  document contains only field:value expressions, then:
>
> - The update() method replaces the matching document with the  document. The update() method does not replace the _id value.
>     For an example, see Replace All Fields.
> - update() cannot update multiple documents.

and about updating specific fields, using `$set`, `$inc` etc.:

> **Update Specific Fields**
>
> If the  document contains update operator expressions, such as those using the $set operator, then:
>
> - The  document must contain only update operator expressions.
> - The update() method updates only the corresponding fields in the    document. For an example, see Update Specific Fields.

And additionally, as I can understand, from your error message Meteor don't allow replacing  whole documents entirely, from the client side. So an option is to use the `$set` operator and set all the values, which in this case is the whole document itself. You may typically skip adding the `_id` key to your document before passing it to the `$set` operator.

Comment: Unfortunately for meteor specifically your solution doesn't seem to work. Minimongo does not support it. The solution I ultimately ended up using was to move my original Entries.update call into a client side meteor method named saveEntry. For whatever reason if you actually do the update from a stub it works. I don't want to not select your answer so if you could add this detail to your solution I'd prefer to mark you as correct.

Comment: ok, so do I understand you correctly, you wrapped the update call inside a method inside Meteor.methods(), like so: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2387816 ?

Comment: sort of... my understanding is you can have Meteor.methods on both the server and the client. One can do a full collection update on the client as long as it is within a client side Meteor.method